# 403 Forbidden ONLY on javascript folder

Tags: web-services, file-permissions, server, permission-denied

I've been trying to trouble shoot this for 3 days and still can't figure it out after going through many other SO questions.

I'm setting up a DigitalOcean VPS using ***Apache 2.4.7***. Setup for 2.4 is different from previous versions, so that may be part of my issue.

### PROBLEM

I'm migrating from shared hosting, and trying to test my site on the new DO VPS. When I go to my new IP address, the site loads, but the following resources get a 404 error:

```
<link href="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/dialog/alert_text.js"></script>
```

Resources in other folders are loading fine; for example, this stylesheet loads without issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main_style.css">
```

I tracked down the issue to a 403 forbidden error on my /javascript directory. This directory is owned by the same owner/group and has the same permissions (755) as every other directory in my web root. But for some reason I cannot access /javascript from my web browser.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

The files do exist on the new server in that location. I've checked that the folder is correct, and that there aren't any strange capitalizations. Everything is working fine on the old server, and all I've done is copy and paste the directory structure to the new server.

There are no *.htaccess* files on the server. And the server wouldn't care if there were, because `Alow Override None` is set.

I've changed my *apache2.conf* back to the default state to make sure there are no strange `<Directory>` directives.

I added a `<Directory>` for the /javascript folder and did `Require all granted`.

I changed permissions on the /javascript folder to `chmod 777` with no effect, then changed back to `chmod 755`.

I'm restarting the web server after each change, but nothing has any effect. I always get a 403 forbidden error on the /javascript directory, even though the owners and permissions are the exact same as every other directory in my web root.

Is there some way to get more info on the 403 error? Some way to find out why it's not allowing access?

### Final note

One thing to note is that I haven't pointed my DNS to DigitalOcean yet since I'm still testing. So the client browser is loading from MY.IP.ADR.ESS/javascript/... rather than MYDOMAINNAME/javascript/.... I can't imagine that would matter, but thought I would mention it anyway.

Comment: Since you're in the middle of migrating, could this be a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Are you saying that someone has hacked my brand new server and is maliciously disallowing me from seeing my /javascript directory?  ;-)

Comment: If your main content is hosted at `yourdomain.com` but the scripts are coming from `my.ip.adr.ess`, the browser may think this is cross-site scripting attack and therefore refuse to load your scripts.

Comment: I don't think so djs, all of the links listed above are relative to the web root. The domain name is not listed. That also wouldn't explain the 403 error when trying to access the /javascript directory from a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, and it's a known problem:  [Ubuntu BUG](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=553173).

The problem was that the folder's name was "javascript", and the fix was simply renaming my /javascript folder to /java-script (or anything OTHER than /javascript).

Basically if you have the javascript-common package installed, it generates the following alias:

```
Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript
```

So my WEBROOT/javascript folder was being redirected to /usr/share/javascript, giving the 403 error.

Hope this helps save someone else a few days of troubleshooting!